# Origin of Vows in Judaism

Tags: minhag, history, nedarim-shevuot

Almost all of Numbers chap. 30 deals with annulation or confirmation of vows. Basically, Nazirite and Vows look the same: somebody invents a trade-off between a desired benefit and a consented restraint. We are not on the same register as mitzvot there. I was wondering where does this practice stems from in the history of Israel, back to the Hebrews or Exile or the Erev rav ?

Comment: It goes back at least as far as Yaakov's וידר יעקב נדר לאמר (Bereishis 28:20).

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "We are not on the same register as mitzvot there." How and why?

Comment: @N.T. in the sense that when mitzvot are the backbone of the life based on Torah, the Vows have no connection to this and appear totally outlandish. They're not on the same register.

Comment: Vows are also part of the Torah and Mitzvos. If they appear outlandish to you, that shows a lack of understanding. See Ramban there.

Answer (score 1):

We see that from the very beginning the avos would utter a neder or a shevua. The earliest reference to a shevuah is in [Lech Lecha 14:22](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209#v22)

> 22 And Abram said to the king of Sodom, "I raise my hand to the Lord,
> the Most High God, Who possesses heaven and earth.

Rashi explains:

> I raise my hand: Heb. הֲרִימֹתִי, lit. I raised. This is an expression
> of an oath: “I raise my hand to the Most High God.” And similarly
> (Gen. 22:16): בִּי נִשְׁבַּעְתִּי [means] “I swear by Myself,” and
> similarly (Gen. 23:13): נָתַתִּי כֶּסֶף הַשָּׂדֶה קַח מִמֶּנִּי
> [means] “I am giving you the price of the field, take it from me.” -
> [from Gen. Rabbah 43:9]

Rav Hirsch translates it as

> I have lifted my hand

and explains this as meaning:

> When I went away I dedicated my hand to Hashem, no
> self-interested motives directed me, but rather I withdrew my hand from
> all other purposes that are lower than Hashem, and dedicated it solely
> to Hashem, so that from all my victory I may take nothing for any
> other purpose, nothing for myself.

Similarly, we see that Eliezer made a shevua to Avraham never to agree to take Yitzchak to his relatives. [Chayei Sara 24:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219/showrashi/true#v2)

> 2 And Abraham said to his servant, the elder of his house, who ruled
> over all that was his, "Please place your hand under my thigh.
>
> 3 And I will adjure you by the Lord, the God of the heaven and the God
> of the earth, that you will not take a wife for my son from the
> daughters of the Canaanites, in whose midst I dwell.

Rav Hirsch translates this as *I will make you swear*.

Finally we see the Torah actually uses the term neder when Yaakov in [Vayaitzei 28:20](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8223/showrashi/true#v20) swears to tithe all that he earns.

> And Jacob uttered a vow, saying, "If God will be with me, and He will
> guard me on this way, upon which I am going, and He will give me bread
> to eat and a garment to wear;

Comment: I am afraid an oath and a vow are different in nature. When the oath is to confirm a permanent status, or agreement, the vow is essentially short term, and reversible by a father, a husband, sages, etc. I like your answer for the oath part but it does not satisfy my curiosity for the vow part. Sorry,,pioni5777

Comment: @Pioni5777 I showed that both a *shevuah* and a *neder* (vow) date back to the avos. I wanted to give the original sources of both. A vow is not necessarily short term as we see with Yaakov since his neder was to last the rest of his life.

Comment: It was an oath, not a vow. Remember I am speaking of the vows in Numbers chap 30, how they can be annulled or let go. Pioni5777

Comment: @Pioni5777 Note that what Yaakov said was a *neder*. That shows that the concept of neder existed from the beginning, the details as shown in Numbers were given at Har Sinai.

Comment: "I am afraid an oath and a vow are different in nature. When the oath is to confirm a permanent status, or agreement, the vow is essentially short term, and reversible by a father, a husband, sages, etc." I think this begins to explain your question, but it is sounds like a mistake. That section of the Torah deals with both vow and oath. Neither one needs to be permanent or temporary. Both can be annulled under the right circumstances. And both serve essential purposes, which is why we find examples in the Torah going back to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

One of the earliest sources of an oath or vow, we find in Bereishis 8:21 that Hashem swears never to bring another flood (see Rashi, based on Shevuos 36a).

For a case of a vow of restraint being taken and then being annulled. The Kli Yakar Bereishis 8:16 Noach forbade himself from yichud and when Hashem told him he may have relations it was annulled.

> וכפי הפשט נוכל לומר שבביאת נח אל התיבה נאסר לו אפילו היחוד עם אשתו כי
> לכך נאמר ובאת אל התיבה אתה ובניך וגו'. וביציאה לא התיר לו עדיין המשגל
> כ״א היחוד לבד הותר לו כי זה המובן ממאמר צא מן התיבה אתה ואשתך ואחר שלא
> הותר לו המשגל כ״א היחוד לבד ע״כ הוסיף נח משלו ואסר על עצמו גם היחוד
> ויצא מן התיבה נח ובניו עד שנאמר לו בפירוש פרו ורבו אז הותרה לו הכל.‏

Comment: Thank you. But I am not interested by Covenants and Oaths. Only by Vows that can be controlled by certain persons and by Nazirite vows alike. pioni5777.